Identifying Variables That Are Always False in Horn-SAT and Enumerating All Solutions
I am studying the satisfiability problem for Horn-SAT and trying to understand how to efficiently identify variables that are always false across all possible solutions. Additionally, I am interested in enumerating all solutions to the Horn-SAT problem, even though I realize that the number of solutions can be potentially exponential.
Here's my current understanding and approach:
Minimal Model Approach: After finding the minimal model using unit propagation (which sets some variables to true), the remaining variables that are not forced to be true are candidates for being false (or true). These variables, which are never needed to satisfy any Horn clause in the minimal model, are assumed to be false. By the way, setting all those variables to false is a solution (the easiest).
False Propagation: Variables that only appear in negative literals (e.g., ¬x in unit clauses) should be set to false, to satisfy those clauses.
Clause Simplification: After assigning values to true variables from the minimal model, I simplify the clause set. Any remaining clauses can be analyzed to see if more variables can be fixed to false without contradicting the satisfiability.
My Algorithmic Approach
To determine whether a variable must always be false, I consider temporarily setting it to true and check if this leads to a contradiction with the minimal model or remaining clauses. If a contradiction arises, the variable must be false in all valid solutions.
My questions are:

Is this approach correct and efficient for identifying variables that
are always false in Horn-SAT problems?

Are there any additional steps or considerations needed to ensure we
accurately identify all such always-false variables?

Considering that enumerating all solutions can be exponentially
complex, what are the best practices or recommended methods for doing
this efficiently, if feasible? For example, if there isn't a smart solution, maybe I would like to generate the next n solutions via a "brute-force GPU" calculation. Maybe, there are smart ways using by example ROBDD.

Is there a known complexity classification specifically for
identifying always-false variables in Horn-SAT problems?



Your false propagation step is incorrect: if a literal is pure, it does not necessarily mean it has to be set to a specific value. But your example there is correct, because it has a unit clause.

There are no such variables (no variables that are false in every satisfying assignment).  The assignment that assigns every variable to true will satisfy every HornSAT formula.

The minimal model find all the variables that must be true. There are 3 types of clauses: unit clause, goal clause (all literals are negative) and definite clause (one literal is positive).

The algorithm for finding the minimal model uses only defined clauses. In my opinion, some clauses won't really be satisfied when we replace the literals with the values that must be true: there will still be clauses with 'free literals'. To find a solution that satisfies all the clauses, we simply set all the remaining variable values to false. But I'm trying to enumerate all the solutions...

@PeterMacGonagan, your questions asks how to "identify variables that are always false across all possible solutions".  There are none.  There is no need to dig into your algorithm; the answer is already clear, for the reasons given in my answer.  (Your comment mentions "find all the variables that must be true".  That is a different question.  "enumerate all the solutions" is yet a third, different question.  We expect you to ask one question per post, and to make sure you are asking the question you want answered.)
